# SAML ADFS loging out

Tags: saml, adfs

I have saml on ADFS. Everything works fine but I have more then one relying party trust. Then when I log in to my one webapp (relying party trust) and log out everything is fine.

But when I log in to first web app and then to second one I can se that on adfs I have cookie: samleSession that combines two sessions and then when I logout from first web app I'm redirected to logout page on second web app and cookies from web site one are not deleted.

Also on ad fs site I can see that there is samllogout cookie. From that moment it is impossible to logoiut from any app.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured the logout URL on ADFS for both apps.?

The way it works is single logout.

When it logs you out of one app., you are logged out of all.

When app1 send a logout request, ADFS deletes the cookies and send a logout response to all apps it knows about.

The apps must then delete their local cookies.